# Trying to enable keybindings for 'outshine': "set before outline-mode is loaded"

Tags: outline-mode

I'm just getting started with `outshine`, and I'm trying to enable outshine's keybindings, but I am stumped by the directive in [the readme](https://github.com/tj64/outshine) to

> ...set the outshine prefix (M-#) in your init file before (!) outline-mode is loaded to enable the outshine keybindings

I don't know how to know when outline-mode is loaded. It's a built-in mode, so I don't mention it in my dotemacs:

```
(require 'outshine)
(setq outline-minor-mode-prefix "\M-#")
(setq outshine-use-speed-commands t)
(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'outshine-hook-function)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'outline-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'outline-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'outline-minor-mode)
```

I'm also not sure if fixing this issue will create the situation I'm hoping for. The outshine *readme* says that outshine uses functionality from [outline-magic.el](https://github.com/jwiegley/nxhtml/blob/master/nxhtml/outline-magic.el), where subtrees can be moved with `M-up` and `M-down` (as in org-mode). That's what I'm hoping for.

Comment: The `require` will load the file if it is not already loaded. So move your defvar before that.

Comment: Your use of `defvar` is wrong.  `defvar` is used to define your own variable, but if you want to set a variable defined elsewhere to a particular value, you should use `setq` (or `setq-default` or `setq-local`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `M-x customize` interface and set the value of `outline-minor-mode-prefix` to `"\M-#"`.

Answer (score 2):

As @kaushalmodi explained, you can do this with the `customize` interface. For the safe of completion, the answer to your original question is that "loading" a library always refers to calling `load` or `require` on it. So, in you case, the `setq` needs to come before the `require` (that's what the docstring is telling you).

```
(setq outline-minor-mode-prefix "\M-#")
(require 'outshine)
```